# Setting up ROS, where to put environment variable?

Tags: ros, environment-variables, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Where should I place the following in Ubuntu 12.04?
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

I want to launch this everytime so that I can just use
roscd beginner_tutorials
everytime.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122666/setting-up-ros,-where-to-put-environment-variable?/) by [lppier](https://answers.ros.org/users/11266/lppier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can put that kind of export in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc` if you use zsh). Thus it will be automatically exported when you open a shell.

Check [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) for more information, as your problem is similar to having to run `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` for each new shell.

In your `~/.bashrc`, you will probably end up having something like this (if you use hydro):

```
# ROS
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.zsh
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2